# Problems publishing a ASP.NET Core 3.1 project to azure Getting a message "Your account is at risk"

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to publish a project from Visual Studio 2019 (fully updated) to azure. But when I try to login I get the message:

Your account is at risk
To help you—and only you—get back into . I verify my account by sms message and enter the old and new email address. But then again when I try to login it again wants me to verify.

At the same time, the email works when I go into Azure portal and I also managed to deply a Microsoft SQL database into Azure SQL. (Though initially I had to add the IP address in the firewall on Azure). Also I updated the location of the user to Thailand (Where I am), in case the system matches the IP address to the location.

OTher things I have in place are for example the resource group. And I also tried to create an app in Azure portal and then publish it to this, but the issue is that I can't login from Visual Studio.

Any suggestions on how I can publish a project to Azure?

------- UPDATE --------------
Still in the loop of login, verify, new password and login again. The screen I get is like this:
[image]

The following screens are:

1. enter code send by sms
2. Enter old and new password
3. Login
   -. And back at the verify screen again.

Any suggestions.

Based on the suggestion below I also removed some of the credentials in the credential manager (those that I thought might have to do with this issue).

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Actually there is no error message. I login, it want to verify me by sms and enter old and new password. After that I login with new password and it wants to verify me again and again new password.

Before though I had an message (though not anymore), forgot exactly what. Something that I was blocked from login in. But when I go to the Azure portal, I see the user is not blocked. Also with that user (which is an admin) I can login and I was able to deploy the database to Azure as well from SQL Studio.
But again, at the moment no error, just a loop of login, verify, new password, login again

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is that there is an old version of your password stored in Credential Manager.

When you try to login via Visual Studio it fails because the password is incorrect. Trying to login with the incorrect password also causes the account to lock, requiring you to verify with SMS.

Comment: Hi Shiraz, thanks for the idea. Did try it and what you mentioned makes sense. But after removing some of the credentials the issue still remains. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Azure WebApp, your best bet is to download the publish profile and use it in your Visual Studio, this way you'll be able to publish your app.